# How to reduce CPU Memory usage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I am working on upload images application which seems working fine for me. I am uploading 100 images.  and when i run this process 4-5 times application crashes out.

This seems to me memory usage issue.. How to reduce that memory. I don't want to my application get crashed.

```
 btn_Cancel.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    btn_Share.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    btn_Back.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    btn_BackTransp.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    btn_BareCode.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

    [self integratedLoaderView];



    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/apiurl /"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
        NSString *str_EstimateNumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtFld_FolderName.text];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";
        string=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *str_time;
        formatter.dateFormat=@"hh.mm.ss a";
        str_time=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *str_AppendString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@",string,str_time];
        NSInteger str_Counter=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[delegate.ary_ImageData count]] integerValue];
        NSString *str_Value=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)str_Counter];
        NSString *str_Username=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Images",txtFld_SelectedFTP.text];
        abc=0;
        for (int i=0;i<[ary_Tosend count]; i++)
        {

            sleep(0.6);

            abc++;
            if ([str_ConnectionStatus isEqualToString:@"WiFi"])
            {
            }
            if ([str_ConnectionStatus isEqualToString:@"Cellular"])
            {
            }
            if ([str_ConnectionStatus isEqualToString:@"No Connection"])
            {
                btn_Cancel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_Share.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_Back.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_BackTransp.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_BareCode.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                NSString *str_Total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[ary_Tosend count]];
                NSString *str_Saved=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[delegate.ary_ImageData count]];
                NSInteger total_Count=[str_Total integerValue]-[str_Saved integerValue];

                [self saveInDBWhenConnectionLost:total_Count];

                [self ShowAlertForCheckInternetConnection];
                return ;
            }
            if ([str_ConnectionStatus isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                btn_Cancel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_Share.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_Back.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_BackTransp.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                btn_BareCode.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                NSString *str_Total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[ary_Tosend count]];
                NSString *str_Saved=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[delegate.ary_ImageData count]];
                NSInteger total_Count=[str_Total integerValue]-[str_Saved integerValue];

                [self saveInDBWhenConnectionLost:total_Count];
                [self ShowAlertForCheckInternetConnection];

                return ;
            }

            NSString *str_fileName;
            str_fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@ %i.jpg",str_EstimateNumber,str_AppendString,abc];
            NSDictionary *params=nil;
            NSData *imageToUpload=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([ary_Tosend objectAtIndex:i],0.25);
            NSString *encodedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageToUpload base64Encoding]];

            params= @{
                     @"categoryName" :txtFld_Category.text,
                     @"folderName"   :txtFld_FolderName.text,
                     @"fileName"     :str_fileName,
                     @"userName"     :str_Username,
                     @"postedFile"   :encodedString,
                     @"accessToken" :@"Q)4%v59!@lyr"
                     };

            AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
            httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFFormURLParameterEncoding;
            [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
            [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request=[httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                  path:@"UploadImages/upload"
                                                            parameters:params];

            NSURLResponse* response=nil;
            NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
            if(data.length)
            {
                NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                if(responseString && responseString.length)
                {
                    [delegate.ary_GetUploadedCount addObject:JSON];
                    [self responseUpload:JSON];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                   ^{
                                       if(i < delegate.ary_ImageData. count)
                                       {
                                           [delegate.ary_ImageData removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                                           [delegate.ary_TotalImages removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                                           [ary_DataToConvert removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                                           [ary_DataToConvert1 removeObjectAtIndex:i];

                                           NSUserDefaults *default_AllImg=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                           [default_AllImg setValue:ary_DataToConvert forKey:@"ImageDetail"];
                                           [default_AllImg synchronize];

                                           NSUserDefaults *default_AllImg1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                           [default_AllImg1 setValue:ary_DataToConvert1 forKey:@"ImageData"];
                                           [default_AllImg1 synchronize];
                                       }
                                   });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Please tell me.

Comment: You need to post your code. If you are loading these images in a loop then you may be keeping all 100 in memory until you are done.

Comment: @Hitesh First make sure it is actually a memory problem: run the app connected to Xcode and watch the memory usage. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you factor your code so that you load an image into memory, upload it, and then release it. Don't build an array of all the images in memory at once.

If you've done that you might still have an autorelease problem.

You might try adding an auto release pool inside your loop:

```
for (NSString *filename in filenames)
{
  @autoreleasepool
  {
    //Your code to load an image and upload it to the server goes here
  }
}
```

However, it's a bit hard to give more specific help until you post your code.

### EDIT

You are using `NSURLConnection`. That class has been deprecated. Use `NSURLSession` instead. That's not the cause of your problem. The cause of your problem is that your are queuing up 100 connections at the same time, with all of their data in memory.

You should use `NSURLSession` and an upload task. With an upload task you just provide a URL to the file and the system takes care of uploading it for you (and manages the memory for you.)

Comment: i posted my code. i am very new to ios. Can you please help

Comment: I have  to queue up with 100 connections.  Because i need response from each connection. what could be other way to do that ?

Comment: I already told you. Use `NSURLSession`, and create upload tasks. You can submit the upload tasks with completion handlers, or set up a delegate to handle the response. The NSURLConnection will handle uploading the files and notify you when each upload is complete.

Comment: If you queue up 100 connections, 96 of them will be waiting anyway. Queue up four, and when one is finished, queue up the next.

Comment: 96 of them will be waiting, but all that memory will be tied up while they wait with the code the OP posted.